# Rally API - Create TestCaseResult - DateTime issue

Tags: c#, .net, api, rally

i'm using the Rally soap API to create a new TestCaseResult against a test case that has been previously created. But I get an error when I create the result - 'Validation error: TestCaseResult.Date should not be null'

Not sure why this should be the case - can you help?

```
    private Boolean createTestResultForTest(String aResult, String aTestCase)
    {
        TestCaseResult myTestCaseResult = new TestCaseResult();
        myTestCaseResult.Build = "1";
        DateTime myDate = DateTime.Now;
        myTestCaseResult.Date = myDate;
        String myQuery = "(FormattedID = " + aTestCase + ")";
        QueryResult myTestCaseReturn = m_rallyService.query(m_workspace, "TestCase", myQuery, "", true, 0, 100);
        long mycount = myTestCaseReturn.TotalResultCount;
        if (mycount > 0)
        {
            TestCase myTestCase = (TestCase)myTestCaseReturn.Results[0];
            myTestCaseResult.TestCase = myTestCase;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
        myTestCaseResult.Verdict = aResult;


        CreateResult myCreateTestResultResult = m_rallyService.create(myTestCaseResult);
        if (hasErrors(myCreateTestResultResult))
        {
            updateStatus("Could not create test result for test case:" + myTestCaseResult.TestCase.Name);
            printWarningsErrors(myCreateTestResultResult);
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            myTestCaseResult = (TestCaseResult)myCreateTestResultResult.Object;
            myTestCaseResult = (TestCaseResult)m_rallyService.read(myTestCaseResult);
            updateStatus("Created TestCaseResult: " + myTestCaseResult.TestCase.Name + ", ref = " + myTestCaseResult.@ref);
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Note that Verdict, Date, and TestCase are all required fields on a TestCaseResult. I see where you're setting myTestCaseResult.Build, myTestCaseResult.Verdict, and myTestCaseResult.Build, however I'm not seeing in your code sample where you set myTestCaseResult.Date?

Comment: Ah yes - I've put it back in now (missed it when trying to remove all of my hacks playing with date formats). I set the date to datetime.now

Comment: But it still isn't working :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you've run into a known bug with Rally's SOAP API that I had forgotten about until just now. Basically the bug is that even when you specify a valid Date/Time object on your TestCaseResult, the SOAP serializer doesn't recognize this unless you also set a specific flag to be true, i.e.:

myTestCaseResult.DateSpecified = true;

Please set this flag, and re-run your code - it should work now :)